# Apache's "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" running 100% CPU - Runaway httpd process

Tags: apache-2.2, php, httpd, mac-osx-server, process

I have this recurring issue where an httpd processes will randomly start running at 100% CPU. Often other httpd processes will join in, and it will continue until I restart Apache. Oddly, the thing it's running 100% CPU on is "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0". Here's the output from one of these:

```
9-0     38787   1/9/391 C   103.14  1323    7   0.0 0.08    4.11    ::1 www.mysite.com  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```

CPU is at 103.14% and it's been 1323 seconds since its last request. It's also stuck in 'C' - closing connection state.

Here's another case where other processes join in running 100% CPU:

```
0-0     12792   0/33/64 W   95.73   1097    0   0.0 0.10    0.39    66.68.237.216   www.mysite.com      POST /page_a.php HTTP/1.1
9-0     12795   1/6/15  C   94.42   1174    0   0.0 0.03    0.07    ::1             www.myserver.com    OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0 
19-0    12986   0/4/41  W   95.67   1011    0   0.0 0.03    0.24    81.237.216.111  www.mysite.com      POST /page_b.php HTTP/1.1 
20-0    12720   0/10/10 W   94.32   1220    0   0.0 0.03    0.03    187.184.103.218 www.mysite.com      POST /page_a.php HTTP/1.1
```

My setup is that this is on OS X Lion 10.4.7. I'm running Apache2 with PHP 5.3. Server Version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch

Some potentially relevant http.conf settings:

```
MaxRequestsPerChild 100000
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 8
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

When I sample the runaway processes, I see each of them show _spin_lock and kevent like so:

```
   Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
    _spin_lock$VARIANT$mp  (in libsystem_c.dylib)        4358
    kevent  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        2179
```

Here is some of the non-repeating Apple code I see:

```
Call graph:
2413 Thread_1080146   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
+ 2413 start  (in httpd) + 52  [0x10f364794]
+   2413 main  (in httpd) + 4045  [0x10f37048d]
+     2413 ap_mpm_run  (in httpd) + 1740  [0x10f3aaabc]
+       2413 perform_idle_server_maintenance  (in httpd) + 703  [0x10f3aa38f]
+         2413 make_child  (in httpd) + 435  [0x10f3aa003]
+           2413 child_main  (in httpd) + 1831  [0x10f3a9e47]
+             2413 clean_child_exit  (in httpd) + 49  [0x10f3a8d31]
+               2413 apr_pool_destroy  (in libapr-1.0.dylib) + 52  [0x10f45761b]
+                 2413 ???  (in libapr-1.0.dylib)  load address 0x10f44b000 + 0xb7b4  [0x10f4567b4]
+                   2413 php_apache_child_shutdown  (in libphp5.so) + 17  [0x10fa3842f]
+                     2413 php_module_shutdown_wrapper  (in libphp5.so) + 9  [0x10f97021d]
+                       2413 php_module_shutdown  (in libphp5.so) + 35  [0x10f970167]
+                         2413 zend_shutdown  (in libphp5.so) + 57  [0x10f9c0692]
+                           2413 zend_hash_destroy  (in libphp5.so) + 53  [0x10f9cb19a]
+                             2413 destroy_op_array  (in libphp5.so) + 271  [0x10f9b91c0]
+                               2413 _efree  (in libphp5.so) + 52  [0x10f9a6312]
+                                 2413 _zend_mm_free_canary_int  (in libphp5.so) + 473  [0x10f9db899]
+                                   2413 free  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 71  [0x7fff8f86170e]
+                                     2413 szone_size_try_large  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 37  [0x7fff8f8240f9]
+                                       2413 _spin_lock$VARIANT$mp  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 30,25,...  [0x7fff8f86336e,0x7fff8f863369,...]
2413 Thread_1080153   DispatchQueue_2: com.apple.libdispatch-manager  (serial)
  2413 _dispatch_mgr_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 54  [0x7fff908fc31a]
    2413 _dispatch_mgr_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 923  [0x7fff908fd78a]
      2413 kevent  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8ed047e6]
```

And then stuff like this:

```
       0x10f4ce000 -        0x10f4d0ff7  mod_reqtimeout.so (??? - ???) <035F872B-8196-3CCE-A4D0-AA8D5C1550EC> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
   0x10f4d4000 -        0x10f4d8ff7  mod_ext_filter.so (??? - ???) <F33A3409-BFBA-3C8F-9FC9-C1BBC17DBE3F> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_ext_filter.so
   0x10f4dd000 -        0x10f4eaff7  mod_include.so (??? - ???) <70E541B9-A864-3FE1-AB85-EBF632FFD376> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
   0x10f4ef000 -        0x10f4f2ff7  mod_filter.so (??? - ???) <2093EE45-E335-3B36-A6BA-6EA4EB7E483C> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
   0x10f4f6000 -        0x10f4f8ff7  mod_substitute.so (??? - ???) <9ED1AB37-EE13-39DC-AB97-98A2B39555B0> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_substitute.so
   0x10f4fc000 -        0x10f501ff7  mod_deflate.so (??? - ???) <E334FEA5-BB4E-36BE-A364-DCE248793345> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_deflate.so
   0x10f506000 -        0x10f50bfff  mod_log_config.so (??? - ???) <61EA3051-8D4A-3A00-B7BC-C68E18CA9479> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
   0x10f511000 -        0x10f512fef  mod_log_forensic.so (??? - ???) <06654BB4-CA2A-3D70-B759-12191119E5C7> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_log_forensic.so
   0x10f516000 -        0x10f516ff7  mod_logio.so (??? - ???) <A3CE3AED-D5FE-3947-8CEB-0A8F4C534E86> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_logio.so
   0x10f51a000 -        0x10f51aff7  mod_env.so (??? - ???) <DE58A08A-C6C9-307B-A077-03A9F1AA14C5> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
   0x10f51e000 -        0x10f524fff  mod_mime_magic.so (??? - ???) <1737F398-6315-31B4-B8B4-57F590F07268> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_mime_magic.so
   0x10f529000 -        0x10f52aff7  mod_cern_meta.so (??? - ???) <B0D4FF96-C96D-3F3A-AECD-431F22A998FA> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_cern_meta.so
   0x10f52e000 -        0x10f52ffff  mod_expires.so (??? - ???) <FE97E6F0-3B84-3CAC-8873-3B1525142041> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_expires.so
   0x10f533000 -        0x10f536ff7  mod_headers.so (??? - ???) <5701D330-D777-3AAF-AEEF-F02D067F851E> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
   0x10f53b000 -        0x10f53cfff  mod_ident.so (??? - ???) <5FDFBB79-3A0C-3439-BF71-74E6A3A4B7AC> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_ident.so
   0x10f540000 -        0x10f542ff7  mod_usertrack.so (??? - ???) <09F36BB5-4F8D-339B-AA52-5FA23A946837> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_usertrack.so
   0x10f546000 -        0x10f547fff  mod_setenvif.so (??? - ???) <D312073B-0320-3810-9535-3AB8EBF83659> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
   0x10f54b000 -        0x10f54cff7  mod_version.so (??? - ???) <4BF2E21C-E452-340E-A6B4-196DBD731CA8> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_version.so
   0x10f550000 -        0x10f566fff  mod_proxy.so (??? - ???) <0169F3B2-A81A-3E23-92FE-8E9B92C38795> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
   0x10f56e000 -        0x10f576ff7  mod_proxy_http.so (??? - ???) <F5B55152-D3D1-34AE-A95A-029F01476A54> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
   0x10f57c000 -        0x10f57efff  mod_proxy_scgi.so (??? - ???) <DFD46BF1-F69D-383B-8B33-5273DD8037E4> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_scgi.so
   0x10f583000 -        0x10f589ff7  mod_proxy_balancer.so (??? - ???) <BC9C283D-8852-3016-8142-96A5675956FA> /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_balancer.so
```

I can post more details as requested.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem once on FreeBSD. See [/server-status shows over 240 requests like “OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0” 200 - “-” “Apache (internal dummy connection)”](http://serverfault.com/questions/132829/server-status-shows-over-240-requests-like-options-http-1-0-200-apac) . The trigger was filesystem snapshots, which momentarily suspended writes to the filesystem so that the system could take a filesystem snapshot. Is your filesystem healthy? Anything unusual on your filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally familiar with the macosx process command line tools, but if those values in the 2nd column are httpd child process pids, then I would try and attach to the process using the [`dtrace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dtrace.1.html) tool and see what they are up to while hung like that.

```
dtrace -p 12345
```

http://www.troeger.eu/cms/?p=255
[man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dtrace.1.html)

Comment: I can sample the process from the activity monitor, and it appears to be endless non-repeating Apple code. I'll post some in my original question

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved this problem by rewriting some of the code. It appears this odd behavior was due to something in my PHP code. I don't know what it was exactly, but I removed a number of global variables and broke several parts into smaller functions, and the issue stopped. It's odd that PHP's timeout wouldn't be triggered, but there you go.